# Assign the output of awk to a specific column in a file

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I have the following example output from a log file where im trying to get the reverse pointer records for the IP Addresses in column 7 below

```
2017-01-09 11:25:22.421     0.306 TCP    192.168.1.2:50599 ->    192.0.2.25:443        500    20000     1
2017-01-09 11:30:11.210     0.000 TCP    192.168.1.2:50503 ->    192.0.2.25:443        100     4000     1
2017-01-09 09:01:22.546     0.000 TCP    192.169.1.2:50307 ->    192.0.2.25:443        100     4000     1
```

If I run this awk command I can extract the reverse records for column 7:

```
cat test.txt | awk '{print $7}'| grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'| xargs -I % bash -c 'echo "$(dig -x % +short)"'
```

How do I get the output from the above command to replace whats in column 7 to update it so it will read for example:

```
2017-01-09 11:25:22.421     0.306 TCP    google.com ->    192.0.2.25:443        500    20000     1
2017-01-09 11:30:11.210     0.000 TCP    ->    192.0.2.25:443        100     4000     1
2017-01-09 09:01:22.546     0.000 TCP    yahoo.com ->    192.0.2.25:443        100     4000     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk only:

```
$ awk '{split($7,a,":"); r=""; c="dig -x " a[1] " +short"; c|getline r; $7=r} 1' file
```

- `split` by `:` to get the ip from `$7` to `a[1]`
- construct the `dig` command for shell to `c` var
- execute it and store result to `r`
- replace `$7` with `r` and `print` with `1`

Not showing any example output as the test file didn't have ips that would return any reverse.

Comment: Thanks James - its not looping through each address in column 7 though - its just taking the first one and displaying that for all addresses in column 7 when I run it .... also if no pointer record available i thought it would just show a blank space ?

Comment: You're right, sorry. `r` didn't get emptied so the previous value would be outputed.